# Difference between kill -9 and -19?

Tags: linux, command, kill

I normally use `kill` command to kill processes. Sometimes it's not killed only with `kill` command. Then I use `-9` option.
I've checked the man page of kill command.

```
$ kill -l
 1) SIGHUP   2) SIGINT   3) SIGQUIT  4) SIGILL   5) SIGTRAP
 6) SIGABRT  7) SIGBUS   8) SIGFPE   9) SIGKILL 10) SIGUSR1
11) SIGSEGV 12) SIGUSR2 13) SIGPIPE 14) SIGALRM 15) SIGTERM
16) SIGSTKFLT   17) SIGCHLD 18) SIGCONT 19) SIGSTOP 20) SIGTSTP
21) SIGTTIN 22) SIGTTOU 23) SIGURG  24) SIGXCPU 25) SIGXFSZ
26) SIGVTALRM   27) SIGPROF 28) SIGWINCH    29) SIGIO   30) SIGPWR
31) SIGSYS  34) SIGRTMIN    35) SIGRTMIN+1  36) SIGRTMIN+2  37) SIGRTMIN+3
38) SIGRTMIN+4  39) SIGRTMIN+5  40) SIGRTMIN+6  41) SIGRTMIN+7  42) SIGRTMIN+8
43) SIGRTMIN+9  44) SIGRTMIN+10 45) SIGRTMIN+11 46) SIGRTMIN+12 47) SIGRTMIN+13
48) SIGRTMIN+14 49) SIGRTMIN+15 50) SIGRTMAX-14 51) SIGRTMAX-13 52) SIGRTMAX-12
53) SIGRTMAX-11 54) SIGRTMAX-10 55) SIGRTMAX-9  56) SIGRTMAX-8  57) SIGRTMAX-7
58) SIGRTMAX-6  59) SIGRTMAX-5  60) SIGRTMAX-4  61) SIGRTMAX-3  62) SIGRTMAX-2
63) SIGRTMAX-1  64) SIGRTMAX
```

What's the difference between `-9` and `-19`?

Comment: Plain `kill` sends `SIGTERM` (15), not `SIGSTOP` (19). Are you asking about the difference between just `kill` and `kill -9`, or between `SIGSTOP` and `SIGKILL`?

Comment: <code>kill -9</code> and <code>kill -19</code>. So, yes <code>SIGSTOP</code> and <code>SIGKILL</code>. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between stop, kill and terminate in Xfce task manager 1.0.1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260675/difference-between-stop-kill-and-terminate-in-xfce-task-manager-1-0-1) Also: [What are the differences between KILL, SUSPEND and TERMINATE of a process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265911/what-are-the-differences-between-kill-suspend-and-terminate-of-a-process)

Comment: The `SIGKILL` (9) interrupt is non-catchable, and terminates the process.  `SIGSTOP` (19) stops process execution, but execution can be seamlessly resumed with a `SIGCONT` (18) interrupt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `kill`, it normally sends `SIGTERM` (15). `SIGSTOP` (19) is for "pausing" a process for resumption later with `SIGCONT` (18). The difference between `SIGTERM` and `SIGKILL` (9) is that `SIGKILL` cannot be "caught" by the receiving process and causes an immediate (and unclean!) termination. The "uncatchable" part is a big deal - `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` are the only signals that cannot be "caught" by a process with an installed signal handler, so they are guaranteed to work.

If you would like an interesting brain teaser that actually came put in a tech interview I had once, look up the difference between `SIGSTOP` and `SIGTSTP`, where each gets used, and in what they do differently from each other. (I've given you a hint already...) It's a nice little piece of *NIX lore.